# Different methods of adding properties to javascript object

Tags: javascript

The following 3 methods i had come across by which properties can be added to an object.

```
> collection = {key0: 'value0'}
{ key0: 'value0' }

> collection.key1 = 'value1';
'value1'

> collection['key2'] = 'value2';
'value2'

> collection
{ key0: 'value0',
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2' }
```

Are there other methods exist by which properties can be added to the object.

Does all the 3 methods do the exact same job ?

Comment: You're not really adding a property in the first case. You're replacing whatever `collection` contained with an object that contains one property. That's not the same as "adding" a property to an already existing object.

Comment: You need to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` and `Object.defineProperties`. Note that `obj.foo` is just syntactic sugar for `obj['foo']`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference here: the first example *creates* a new object (this is called an "object literal"), the other two change an already existing object.

The second and third examples change the `collection` object in the same way, the difference lies in the inability to use a variable property name in the dot notation:

```
// Let's say we have an object
var collection = { key0 : "value0" };

// Let's say for some reason we want to use a variable as a property name
var keyName = "key1";

// This won't assign "someValue" to the property "key1" as you would expect
// instead it will assign it to the property "keyName" (the string, not the variable)
collection.keyName = "someValue"; // OOPS

// With bracket notation you can use a variable (or any expression) as a property name
collection[keyName] = "value1"; // Sweet
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement defines a new object with a single property named `key0`.

The second statement assigns a value to the object's property named `key1`. Since the object doesn't have its own property named `key1`, the property is created.

The third statement is identical in effect to the second statement. The main reasons to use bracket notation instead of dot notation are:

- properties with special characters, e.g., `collection["foo-bar"]` refers to a property called `foo-bar`, but `collection.foo-bar` performs a subtraction operation on `collection.foo` and `bar`.
- variable property names, e.g., you can do `var propName = "key0"; collection[propName] = ...`

The only other way to define properties is with `Object.defineProperty` (and the multiple variant `Object.defineProperties`). This allows you to define properties that behave in special ways.

```
Object.defineProperty(collection, "key3", {
    enumerable: false,    // property will not show up in for-in loops
    configurable: false,  // property cannot be changed
    set: function(val) {
        alert("we tried to set key3 to " + val);
    },
    get: function() {
        alert("this code runs when we get collection.key3");
        return "value3";
    }
});

collection.key3 = 6;  // alerts "we tried to set key3 to 6"
collection.key3;      // alerts "this code runs when we get collection.key3"
                      // and returns the string "value3"
```